# How to scroll two scroll bar on same webpage using python selenium(website:linkedin Sales Navigator)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRjdk.png)I just wanted to know how can I scroll in sales navigator on linkedIn as it consist of two scroll bar on the same web page.I'm not able to access the scroll bar in the code.
Can anyone help at the earliest?

Comment: Can you add your code ? Are you getting any error ?

Comment: I'm not getting errors but not able to scroll the particular webpage.

Comment: Can you add your code ?

Comment: I have added the image

Comment: Used this,
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
Also,
driver.switch_to.frame('search-results-container')
Also,
Clickandhold = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ("button[aria-label=Next]"))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0],scrollIntoView();",Clickandhold)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.